# Error when trying to delete EKCalendar from EKStore

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar

I am trying to remove a EKCalendar that I have created inside my iOS app using the following method.

```
- (void)DeleteCalendar
{
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    EKEntityType type = EKEntityTypeEvent;
    NSArray *calendars = [eventStore calendarsForEntityType:type];

    for (EKCalendar *thisCalendar in calendars){
        NSLog(@"Calendar: %@", thisCalendar.title);
        if ([thisCalendar.title isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",CALENDARPREFIX, _currentCName]]) {
            NSError *err;
            [eventStore removeCalendar:thisCalendar commit:YES error:&err];
            if (!err) {
                NSLog(@"deleted %@", thisCalendar.title);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"%@", err.localizedDescription);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However when I run this method I get the following error from the last **else** statement.

> That event does not belong to that event store

I have read that there is a bug in **removeCalendar:** however was hoping someone else may have experienced this and can help me fix the issue.

Comment: You seem to have a big typo in your question's code where you try to delete a calendar. Make sure you copy and paste real code to avoid such problems.

Comment: Whoops It is a copy and paste I declared store twice during testing.. was trying to figure it out I have since updated the question to remove the confusion. However still have the same problem.

Comment: You still have a big typo since your posted code doesn't actually call anything called `removeCalendar`. Again, copy and paste real code.

Comment: wowsers... that was weird. I did copy and paste... I am not sure what happened there. the only thing I removed were some comments after i copied and pasted... so must have just fudged it up. sorry about that.

Comment: `removeCalendar` isn't working for me with an error: ""We can't delete the calendar because no other calendars support reminders." - whereas I have dozens of other calendars that support Reminders. What's going on?